# CloudDeploy a WordCloud of Values from Databin

Tags: cloud-deploy, databin

I have String values stored in a databin. I want users to add values to the databin through webform at datadrop.wolframcloud.com or via the link created by evaluating:

```
(* 1 *) bin = Databin["GpqwBQQJ"]["WebForm"]
```

I then want to CloudDeploy a WordCloud that takes the updated values of the databin and displays a WordCloud like this:

```
(* 2 *) CloudDeploy[WordCloud[Values[Databin["GpqwBQQJ"]]]]
```

It will only display Strings that were in the Databin at the time I evaluated line 2, and generated a new url. Any subsequent additions to the databin do not result in a new WordCloud when I refresh the page.

I read this post: [CloudDeploy a Manipulate...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125837/clouddeploy-a-manipulate-with-dependent-functions?rq=1) and I tried setting "Evaluate" permissions, but no luck. I have a hunch that [this user](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138783/data-added-via-web-call-to-databin-not-shown-on-subsequent-plot) was on to a similar problem, but the post lacks enough code to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like below:

- 2nd argument "sameURLtest" of `CloudDeploy` will deploy to the same URL every time you redeploy, so you do not create a plethora of junk test deployments with different randomly generated URLs.
- `Delayed` will force any new reload of URL to rerun the code: access the data bin and regenerate new `WordCloud`
- `Rasterize` converts `WordCloud` to an image before deployment and allows to control image quality. This helps to display `WordCloud` better on the web. Check out also `ImageResolution` option.

I hope this helps, let me know if this works for you.

```
CloudDeploy[
    Delayed[
        Rasterize[
            WordCloud[Values[Databin["GpqwBQQJ"]]],
        ImageSize->500]
    ],
"sameURLtest",
Permissions->"Public"]
```

Basically `Delayed` does the trick. There is a nice related workflow that shows how `Delayed` works at the very end:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SetUpAWebGallery.html

Comment: Fantastic! This works beautifully. Thank you =)